# How to extend an existing orthogonal set of vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms

Suppose I have $k$ vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ that are orthogonal to each other ($k \ll n$). Is there an efficient way to find another vector that is orthogonal to all these given vectors?

If we put the $k$ vectors in a $k \times n$ matrix, denoted by $A$, then the problem is identical to finding a vector in the null space of $A$. Of course one can resort to the method of solving an underdetermined linear system to find the null space of $A$, but by doing this we have got all the vectors that span the null space of $A$. For $k \ll n$, this is definitely not efficient, since I only need one vector in the null space.

I'm wondering if there exists a smarter way.

Comment: Could you do a change of coordinates so that all your $k$ orthogonal vectors point along coordinate axes, and then just take any vector pointing along one of the other $n-k$ axes?

Comment: I think finding this transformation is more costly than finding the null space, since finding the null space only takes $k-1$ Gaussian eliminations.

Comment: Would guessing a linearly independent vector and then taking the orthogonal part work? You can make a vector orthogonal to a given set of vectors using methods similar to Gram-Schmidt...

Comment: @JohannesKloos That's a good point. If I have a linearly independent vector, then only one step of Gram-Schmidt is enough, which basically involves calculating $k$ projections. But is there a way to get a linearly independent vector (except guessing)?

Comment: @YuanGao, following the comment by Johannes, you can **always** pick an element from the canonical basis in $\;\Bbb R^n\;$ to add it to your linearly independent set and get a lin. ind. set, so your "guessing" gets seriously reduced. After this, appl the first step of Gram-Schmidt, i.e. the orthogonal projection of the above chosen vector on the span of the first $\;k\;$ given vectors  (Without the normalizing part as you're only interested in orthogonality).

Comment: @DonAntonio Nice insight! If we look at the worst case complexity of this method, it seems to be $O(nk^2)$, because in the worst case we need to pick $k+1$ elements from the canonical basis, and for each Gram-Schmidt step we need to calculate $k$ projections, and for each projection we need an inner-product operation that takes $O(n)$. The time complexity for performing Gaussian elimination on the matrix $A$ also takes $O(nk^2)$. But at least we have an algorithm that is asymptotically as fast as finding the null space :)

Comment: Yup @YuanGao, it looks so.

Comment: Can't you eliminate the dependence on $n$ by assuming that all entries after $k+1$ are zero? That is, truncate your $k$ given vectors to length $k+1$, find something orthogonal to these vectors in ${\bf R}^{k+1}$, then pad it out with zeros.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The truncated vectors are not necessarily orthogonal to each other. Consider a counterexample where we are given $[1,-1,1,-1]$ and $[1,-1,1,3]$. Your method might return a vector like $[1,1,0,0]$, which is invalid.

Comment: Why is $(1,1,0,0)$ invalid? Isn't it orthogonal to the other vectors?

Comment: Similar question posted to MO without any notice at either site, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/168721/is-finding-a-single-vector-in-the-null-space-as-difficult-as-discovering-the-who

Answer (score 3):

You could normalize the $k$ vectors and make them the columns of a matrix $Q$.  Then $I - QQ^T$ is the projection onto the orthogonal complement of the span of the $k$ vectors.  Any nonzero column of this matrix is orthogonal to the $k$ vectors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with random guess-and-check is nondeterministic behavior. As $\lim k \to n$, the time take is going to get longer and longer. That is why finding something in the null space would make more sense, unless you can figure out an easy transformation that will turn the existing orthogonal vectors into the unit coordinate vectors: $\vec e_1, \vec e_2 \ldots$, and from there you can generate the remaining vectors. After you have all the vectors you want, inverse transform them back to the original coordinate system.

Comment: I agree that guess-and-check and seeking transformation to standard basis would be inefficient. But does that mean finding a single vector in the null space is as hard as discovering the whole null space?

Comment: I would say that finding the whole null space is better, since when you have only a few vectors in  the system, the row-reduction doesn't take all that long to perform.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to pick the first $k+1$ components of each vector and form $v_1,\ldots,v_k$ in $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$. Then you can do the cross product of these vectors $w=v_1\times\ldots\times v_k\in \mathbb{R}^{k+1}$. Finally, you can define $v=(w,0,\dots,0)\in\mathbb{R}^n$.
If $w=0$ start to pick the components from the second and define $v=(0,w,0,\dots,0)\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and so on. However, I believe this would be useful only if $k$ is much smaller then $n$, because you need to compute a determinant.

Comment: The cross product is only defined for vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{3}.$

Comment: @ttb There is a well known generalization of the cross product of 2 vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to k vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$. Check the section - Multilinear Algebra - in wikipedia for more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product